# How to execute python code and airflow macro in a BashOperator?

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I am trying to execute the following task in Airflow:

```
time_zone = "America/New_York"
t1= BashOperator(
    task_id='example_task',
    bash_command=('script.sh --arg1 hello '
                  f'--arg2 {{ execution_date + timedelta(days=1).astimezone(pytz.timezone({time_zone})) }}'),
    dag=dag)
```

The problem I have is with the `bash_command`. I am trying to execute python code and use a macro inside the `bash_command`, but the script above yields `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed`.

My question is: Is what I am trying to do possible and if so, how? I guess I am just scripting jinja in the wrong way... but I am not sure.

Comment: I've been able to run airflow macros in a bash script as you described, so I'm guessing the bash script itself may have failed somehow. You could further debug by running the bash image with something like `echo {{ execution_date + timedelta(days=1).astimezone(pytz.timezone({time_zone})) }}` to see what that macro is actually resolving to.

Comment: So you are saying that this `{{ execution_date + timedelta(days=1).astimezone(pytz.timezone({time_zone})) }}` runs fine in `BashOperator`, where `execution_date` is an airflow macro and the rest is python code?

Comment: I didn't try evaluating that exact string. I tried playing around with the jinja formatting and I'd recommend changing your string to `{{{{ execution_date + timedelta(days=1).astimezone(pytz.timezone('{time_zone}')) }}}}`, doing your `stringvar.format(time_zone=time_zone)`, and then jinja should be able to resolve the execution_date from there. You might also want to change `timedelta` to `macros.timedelta` if you get a `timedelta is undefined` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the above does not work is because I was using both `jinja2` and python `f-strings` at the same time, thus resulting in confusion.

There is no way (which I have found) to combine the two directly from the `bash_command=`. A wrapper python function to execute the bash command and a `PythonOperator` to execute the wrapper function is a solution, as it provides great flexibility over the usage of the airflow macros (the reason why I use `jinja2` in the `bash_command=` and python code.

It's not the cleanest solution, but it works.